# How to dynamically populate an object from its own values?

Tags: javascript

How to dynamically populate an object from its own values? Exemple:

```js
const user = {
    name: "john",
    surname: "smith",
    fullname: `${this.name} ${this.surname}`
}

expected output: user.fullname= "john smith"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with everything in JavaScript, there's at least 3 different ways to do roughly the same thing...

### Using an object-literal property getter:

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Custom property getters/setters in object-literals requires browser/engine support for ECMAScript 5 (aka ECMAScript 2009) - so this works in **all** modern web-browsers today (but won't work in ECMAScript 3.x browsers like Internet Explorer 6 through Internet Explorer 8, but IE9 and later supports it):

```
const user = {
    name: "john",
    surname: "smith",
    get fullName() {
        return this.name + " " + this.surname;
    }
};

console.log( user.fullName );
```

### Using `Object.defineProperty`:

This is also a post-ECMASCript 5 (ECMASCript 2009) feature, so only Internet Explorer 9 or later supports it (though IE8 *does* support `Object.defineProperty` for DOM objects).

```
const user = {
    name: "john",
    surname: "smith"
};

Object.defineProperty( user, 'fullName', {
  get: function() { return this.name + " " + this.surname; }
});

console.log( user.fullName );
```

### Alternatively, using `setPrototypeOf`:

This requires ECMAScript 6 (ECMAScript 2015) support, though IE11 does support `Object.setPrototypeOf`.

```
class User {

    get fullName() {
        return this.name + " " + this.surname;
    }
}

const user = {
    name: "john",
    surname: "smith"
};

Object.setPrototypeOf( user, User ); // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

console.log( user );
```

### Alternatively (for very, very old JavaScript engines), using a function property:

This approach avoids `Object.defineProperty`, but means you have to invoke `fullName` as a function (i.e. with `()`) instead of as a parameterless property getter:

```
const user = {
    name: "john",
    surname: "smith"
};

user.fullName = function() {
    return this.name + " " + this.surname;
};

console.log( user.fullName() );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of getter like below.

```js
const user = {
    name: "john",
    surname: "smith",
    get fullname() {
      return  `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
    }
}

console.log(user.fullname);
```

Comment: Looks like first answer is edited based on this one.

Comment: here is the revisions https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61270095/revisions

Comment: He did however already have `class User {

    get fullName() {
        return this.name + " " + this.surname;
    }
}
`